# Godaddy .net site hosting issue - No Such host is known Error

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, iis

I need help on hosting my .net application to **GoDaddy** server since their tech team is not sure about this issue. My application was developed on **C#.net** and database as **mysql**. I compiled my application and did publish and using filezilla i transferred entire files to GoDaddy directory.

Now the application loads, the issue is seems with Database side. Whenever i try to open a page which has database interaction i am getting the following error

[image]

The connection string i am using to connect is marked with red box in the screen shot, there **Server** is GoDaddy Database server IP which i am using.

I don't know why i am getting that error. To confirm that it is not coming from application code side, i tried to connect to GoDaddy server database from my localhost. In that case the same error throws while opening db **connection**.

So in that case what and where will be the issue?

Can someone with previous **GoDaddy** hosting experience help me to identify the issue?

Is this something related to connectionstring issue?

Comment: If you can't connect from a local machine either, why do you think it's GoDaddy- or even connectionstring-specific issue? Basic networking troubleshooting applies here.

Comment: Yes i asked them and they were not able to figure it out. anyway now the issue solved Mark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error essentially means the IP cannot be resolved to a host name.

A few things that might be going on here:

- The external IP does not work internally in which case, you should modify your connection string so that it uses the internal host name and port if necessary (it should be available somewhere in GoDaddy).
- You have the wrong IP and/or port. Check your connection settings.
- You are using the wrong format for your connection string. Double check the format against the provider. I have seen connection strings for MySQL where the port is a separate argument, like this:

**Connection String**:       `Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

Comment: you said it right. I given port and server separately, now it is getting connection to server DB.

Comment: @Nithin Have you ask your hosting provider about the correct connection string that you need to use?

Comment: @DouglasThomas i checked with them, They didn't notice this connection string problem when i shared it with them and then as per Juan's suggestion i splitted SERVER and PORT separately. Now the issue gone and connection is able to establish.

Answer (score 0):

That "server" portion of your connection string, even with parts blotted out, looks awfully long.  It should look like this:  000.000.000.000.  The four parts should be numbers from 0-255, and not all four parts have to be three digit numbers.  If there's ":3306" afterward, take that out.

Comment: That is a port number. 192.168.0.1,3306 is a valid server address.