# godaddy hosting:System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

[this is the error][1]I am able to connect to the godaddy database with connectionnstring "server = ***.***.***.***; port=****; uid=****;pwd=****;database=****" but when I type my url to browser it is showing this error

Comment: go to the link below  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535047/godaddy-net-site-hosting-issue-no-such-host-is-known-error/46103330#46103330"  this is my problem but in my case when I request my url to browser It is showing same error as discussed in the link above...

Comment: It has been solved...the error is in the web.xml file in which security tags was not set

Comment: thanx for your interest